# How do I style JUST the reflection of the content without affecting its original source?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I’m using `-webkit-box-reflect` to reflect a div and everything inside it.

However I would like to know how can I reflect the content AND be able to fiddle with just the reflection in CSS. So let's say I want change the opacity of just the reflection, how would I go about doing it?

Oh and just as a curiosity, how do I NOT give the reflection a mirrored effect using `-webkit-box-reflect`? So instead it looks like I've just multiplied the div/content? Can be below, above, or beside it.

```css
    .div1 {
        color: white;
        background-color:green;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        margin left: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 200px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        top: 15px;
        -webkit-box-reflect: right 1px;
    }
    
    
    .div2 {
        color: white;
        background-color:blue;
        position: absolute;
        height: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        margin left: 50px;
        left: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 200px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        top: 70px;
        -webkit-box-reflect: below 1px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
       <head>

          <div class="div1">div1 test</div>
 
          <div class="div2">div2 test</div> 

       </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: *"[Note:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-box-reflect) This feature is not intended to be used by Web sites. To achieve reflection on the Web, the standard way is to use the CSS [element()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element) function."*

Comment: I made your code into a runnable snippet. Because there were some errors, I fixed those too. I normally wouldn't do this, since it could take away the incentive of the question, but since the code seemed to be for illustration and as a base for experimentation, I thought it wouldn't be a problem. If it is, feel free to rollback the change, or ask if you don't have sufficient privileges to do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define -webkit-gradients in the same line or even images etc.

```
-webkit-box-reflect: below 0px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), to(white));
```

[Source](http://designshack.net/articles/css/mastering-css-reflections-in-webkit/)

You really shouldn't be using this, though. There are better ways to achieve this with better browser support.

I think displaying the same content twice is possible only in jQuery.
[Source](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)